# Datatable (JQuery and Bootstrap) customization

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, datatables

Am I using DataTables and jQuery & Bootstrap. I initialize tables with custom labels and "sDom": 'lftpir'.

It is unclear where the inscription "Show per page:" appears from.

How to remove the inscription "Show per page:"? Thank you in advance

[image: Screen with label]